# Binary XML file line #74: Error inflating class ImageView

Tags: android

when I try to run my application on a device running api 21, my device grabs the application and runs it perfectly. When I try to run it on my samsung 3 device which is running api 18, my app crases with the error:

```
3-03 10:08:22.075 7090-7090/ E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #74: Error inflating class ImageView
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #74: Error inflating class ImageView
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
                                                                                  at jamcloud.skyrealm.com.jamcloud.Login.onCreate(Login.java:77)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                               Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f020099 a=-1 r=0x7f020099}
                                                                                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2063)
                                                                                  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
                                                                                  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:127)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:58)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:54)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:95)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:938)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:992)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:684)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
                                                                                  at jamcloud.skyrealm.com.jamcloud.Login.onCreate(Login.java:77) 
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133) 
                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The things that I have tried so far is adding in,

```
dexOptions {
    incremental = true;
    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g" // 2g should be also OK
}
```

Which did not work, I also tried adding the background image to all the drawable folders and I even went as far as to try to just delete the background image off the app. Thanks for the help!
Cheers,
Rocky~

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/signinbg">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/password"
        android:layout_below="@+id/password"
        android:text="login"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:background="@color/Blueish"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:background="@android:drawable/edit_text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/edit_text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
        android:ems="10"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:password="true"
        android:singleLine="true"

        android:gravity="center"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Not registered yet? Sign up!"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/Register"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:text="Sign in"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView4" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Username"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:textSize="23dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/username"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Password"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:textSize="23dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/username"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Forgot Password?"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:id="@+id/ForgotPassword"
        android:layout_below="@+id/password"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView4" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your xml file?

Comment: @Geralt_Encore, I have updated with the xml

Comment: `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f020099 a=-1 r=0x7f020099}`

Comment: @Bob Malooga, what could that issue be?

Comment: Maybe you are trying to use a resource which belongs to a different style/theme.

Answer (score 0):

I only delete the drawable-v21 folder and it worked.

Comment: Because there were styles.xml and theme.xml in the values folder, which referred resources which are only found in the API Level 21+.